# To Send Email to Multiple Recipients in Liferay

Tags: email, liferay

I wanted to know how to send email to multiple recipients n liferay 6.2 when a new content has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way without need writing any line of code is using Web Content notifications, which are broader described here https://www.liferay.com/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-setup-email-notifications

Another way of achieving email notifications is custom definition of workflow in kaleo workflow which is described a bit here https://www.liferay.com/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-kaleo-email-notifications

Last option is some custom development based on `com.liferay.mail.service.MailServiceUtil.java`

I hope any of these option is useful for you.